# Flutter launch screen while app is checking if user is logged in

Tags: flutter, dart, splash-screen, launch-screen

I recently built a flutter app. I have a method that checks if a user is logged in or not and shows the appropriate screen after confirming the check. If a user is not logged in it will return the login screen but if a user has logged in already it should show the home screen. However, if a user is logged in, it will show the login screen for a second or two before showing the home screen. The code for checking if a user has logged in

```
class CheckAuth extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CheckAuthState createState() => _CheckAuthState();
}

class _CheckAuthState extends State<CheckAuth> {
  bool isAuth = false;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _checkIfLoggedIn();
  }

  void _checkIfLoggedIn() async {
    SharedPreferences localStorage = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    var token = localStorage.getString('token');
    if (token != null) {
      setState(() {
        isAuth = true;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Widget child;
    if (isAuth) {
      child = HomePage();
    } else {
      child = Login();
    }
    return Scaffold(
      body: child,
    );
  }
}
```

This is the main function code

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme:
          ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blueGrey,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: CheckAuth(),
    );
  }
}
```

I would like to show a splash screen while the check is performing in the background and show the screen that is correct

Answer (score 5):

You are awaiting `SharedPreferences.getInstance()` in your `_checkIfLoggedIn()` function. However, this function cannot be awaited because I do not believe flutter has an async init function.

The solution is to use a `Future` builder that will show what is needed based on the state of the async call.

There are 3 possible states:

- The program is waiting for the future to finish.
- The future has finished and is false.
- The future finishes and is true.

```dart
class CheckAuth extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CheckAuthState createState() => _CheckAuthState();
  }

  class _CheckAuthState extends State<CheckAuth> {
  bool isAuth = false;
  Future<bool> loginCheckFuture;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    loginCheckFuture = _checkIfLoggedIn();
  }

  Future<bool> _checkIfLoggedIn() async {
    SharedPreferences localStorage = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    var token = localStorage.getString('token');
    if (token != null) {
      return true;
    }   
    return false;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Widget child;
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: loginCheckFuture,
      builder: (context, snapshot){

        if(snapshot.hasData){
          if(snapshot.data == true){
          child = HomePage();
          } else {
            child = Login();
          }
        } else{
          // future hasnt completed yet
          child = yourLoadingWidget();
        }
        
        return Scaffold(
          body: child,
        );
      }
    );    
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

_checkIfLoggedIn() is an async function that takes some time to complete the execution. Login screen is shown at first because isAuth is initialized to false.You can show a loader while the _checkifLoggedIn is executed;

you can also use an enum for this

```
enum AuthState{
  unkown,loggedIn,loggedOut
}
```

create a  variable of type AuthState and initialize it to unknown since we dont know wheather the user is loggedin or not at first.

```
AuthState authState= AuthState.unknown
```

after the _checkIfLoggedIn() is completed you can set it to AuthState.loggedIn or AuthState.loggedOut

Comment: Could you kindly show the working for this?